# Draw image from text file using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, text, draw, glut

I have a text file containing the vertices of a triangle. I would like to draw this triangle in an OpenGL window; however, I am quite new to OpenGL and am not sure where to get started.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide a general outline as to how I might get started with this problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nothing to do with OpenGL. Study about file input and parsing in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/112226) should help you.